# \input running into Misplaced \noalign errors on TeXShop (but not Overleaf)

Tags: overleaf, input, texshop

A minimum working example on Overleaf of my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Title}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{skip=1.5pt}
    \caption{Tablename}
    \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
                \midrule\midrule\addlinespace
                & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Outcome}} \\
                \cmidrule{2-5} & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)  \\
                \midrule\addlinespace
                Panel A:  \\
                \midrule\addlinespace
                \input{file_1.tex} 
                \addlinespace\midrule\addlinespace
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
                \item \textit{Notes:}  Surveillance capacity panel above/below median dummy. Events are carried out by non-governmental actors. Observation at the prefecture - semiyear level.   \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

where `file_1.tex` contains:

```
Variable       &       1.283** &       1.474***&       0.296   &       0.369   \\
                    &     (0.531)   &     (0.551)   &     (2.610)   &     (2.528)   \\
```

For some reason, this same code (with files placed in the same folder etc.) does not work when I try running it with TeXShop on my computer. Specifically, the console produces these logs:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./filename.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttabl
e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.
sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatche
s.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilechec
k.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounte
r.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.d
ef)
No file filename.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestr
ing.sty)) (./file_1.tex)
./filename.tex:39: Misplaced \noalign.
\addlinespace ->\noalign 
                         {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@addspace }{\@addsp...
l.39    }
```

Oddly enough, directly copying and pasting the contents of `file_1.tex` in place of the `\input` produces the intended output on both Overleaf and TeXShop, which goes against my understanding of how `input` works. It's unfortunately not practical to copy and paste everything for the project that I am working on, given the number of instances in which `input` occurs. Finally, this same code was also working in TeXShop a few days ago, but I've done a few things in the meantime and I'm not sure what exactly broke the process down -- these include updating files with `tlmgr` as well as doing a fresh install of `threeparttable` and `ucs` (for utf8x) when the `.sty` for these packages apparently could not be found.

I'm a bit lost as to figuring out how this might have happened, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: unrelated to the question but avoid doing this `\scalebox{.8}{`  applying scaling to tables produces font and rules inconsistent with the rest of the document.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  yes, that fixed my problem - I'm guessing it was the same update that caused the issue. Thanks!